# Prior art request for US20120203457 A1 - Showing a calendar on a map with route optimization between points

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, rejected, us20120203457

Multiple claims are made in this patent application that could be summarized as follows

1. Show travel routes between two or more events on a map with a display
2. Optimize a schedule based on the most efficient route between two or more events/appointments, displaying the result on map
3. Using the start/end time of an event, determine the best route between two or more events/appointments producing a schedule
4. Show points of interest on a map, enriched based on their source (for instance, a restaurant shown on the map from Zagat's restaurant guides would be enriched with Zagat's reviews). These points of interest can be added to your schedule and optimized like other events.

None of these things are groundbreaking, and I think there should be plenty of examples of prior art out there to present to the examiner. Prior art needs to be from before Feb 4, 2011.

[Google Patent Page for US20120203457 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120203457?dq=casey%20group&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tCQbVOKQEYqtyASn54CADw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA)

**Systems and methods for visualizing events together with points of interest on a map and routes there between**

- **Publication number**:  US20120203457 A1
- **Publication type**:    Application
- **Application number**:  US 13/366,964
- **Publication date**:    Aug 9, 2012
- **Filing date**: Feb 6, 2012
- **Priority date**:   Feb 4, 2011
- **Inventors**:   Richard P. CASEY, Sandipsinh G. Ghummad
- **Original Assignee**:   The Casey Group

**ABSTRACT:**

> This disclosure relates to providing systems and methods for
> visualizing events together with points of interest on a map and
> routes there between. The disclosure includes a data processing
> apparatus having a display and a processor, where the processor is
> configured to run a module stored in memory. The module is configured
> to obtain event information associated with a plurality of events, to
> obtain a schedule of the plurality of events, to obtain travel routes
> between at least two consecutive events of the schedule, and to
> instruct the display to display the travel routes between the at least
> two consecutive events of the schedule on a map. The module can be
> further configured to obtain location information on a plurality of
> points of interest (POIs), to obtain tag information associated with
> the plurality of POIs from at least one directory.

**Claim 1**

> a processor, in communication with the one or more interfaces, and
> configured to run a module stored in memory that is configured to
> obtain event information associated with a plurality of events,
> wherein the event information includes a start time for one of the
> plurality of events, to obtain travel routes between at least two
> consecutive events, and to instruct the display to display the travel
> routes between the at least two consecutive events on a map.

**Claim 11**

> A method comprising: receiving event information associated with a
>
> plurality of events;
>
> receiving event information associated with a plurality of events;
> obtaining a schedule of the plurality of events, wherein the schedule
> is based on the event information associated with the plurality of
> events;
>
> obtaining travel routes between at least two consecutive
> events;
>
> and displaying the travel routes on a map.

**Claim 15**

> An apparatus comprising: one or more interfaces configured to provide
>
> communication with a computing device; and
>
> a processor, in communication with the one or more interfaces, and
> configured to run a module stored in memory that is configured to
> receive a schedule request from the computing device, the schedule
> request including event information associated with a plurality of
> events, the event information including a start time and an end time
> for a schedule of the plurality of events, to obtain distance
> information between at least one pair of the plurality of events, to
> determine the schedule of the plurality of events based on the
> distance information, and the start time and the end time for the
> schedule, and to provide a schedule response to the computing device,
> the schedule response including the schedule of the plurality of
> events.

**Claim 21**

> A data processing apparatus comprising:
>
> a display; and
>
> a processor configured to run a module stored in memory that is
> configured to obtain location information of a first point of interest
> (POI), to obtain tag information associated with the first POI from a
> directory, to instruct the display to display the first POI on a map,
> and to instruct the display to display a portion of the tag
> information associated with the first POI, wherein the portion of the
> tag information is determined based on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

This application is deemed abandoned as the applicant has not responded to a communication from the patent office. (Abandonment on 1.6.2016)